# Calling startActivityOnResult() automatically calls onPause(), onStop() and onDestroy() methods of current activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am starting another activity by calling `startActivityForResult()` and after pressing back button my previous activity's onCreate Method is called hence recreating the whole activity.

On debugging I found that calling `startActivityOnResult()` automatically calls

```
onPause()
onStop()
onDestroy()
```

methods of current activity. Is it normal behaviour because i had read it calls only `onPause()` method on starting another activity.

This is my code:

```
    @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}


public void showScore(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(StartMultipleChoiceActivity.this, ScoreActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("blockPosition", blockPosition);
    int itemVisited=submittedAnswers.size();
    i.putExtra("itemVisited", itemVisited);
    int itemCorrect=correctAnswers.size();
    i.putExtra("itemCorrect", itemCorrect);
    startActivityForResult(i,1);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: it should call onpause() and onStop() only.

Comment: its very normal  .. see here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: but it is calling onDestroy() as well

Comment: why it is calling onDestroy()? Any idea?

Comment: where do you call the `startActicityForResult()` paste that method or piece of code where you call startActivityForResult()..

Comment: Place here your onPause() and onStart() method.

Comment: And last question - what is your activity name?

Comment: I tried by removing onPause() onStop() onDestroy() methods but no improvement.It is still calling onCreate() method after returning back to this activity

Comment: How much memory do you have? Is it emulator?

Comment: i am running it on emulator and allocated memory 1024mb

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8961/discussion-between-nishant-and-biovamp)

Comment: I tested it on device it is working fine but problem is when running on emulator after I allocated the memory in runConfiguration -> Target-> giving Additional emulator command line option as 1024

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same behavior, on a real device. onDestroy() of the launching activity is called after it calls startActivityForResult() and onCreate() of the launched activity has been called, but before onActivityResult() was ever called. Very odd. Any news on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onPause()` and `onStop()` are perfectly normal. Those will be called any time your activity no longer has foreground input (`onPause()`) and no longer is visible (`onStop()`).

`onDestroy()` should only be called if you are somehow finishing the activity yourself, or perhaps if you are launching an activity in a separate app and Android needs to terminate your own app's process to free up RAM.

Comment: May be due to low memory only activity is getting destroyed on emualator. Apk file size of my app is 30 MB and I was unable to upload it on the emulator as it dispalys an error Insufficient memory. As suggested in one of the blog i manually allocated the memory and then only this problem comes. App is running perfectly on real device

Comment: @Nishant: "May be due to low memory only activity is getting destroyed on emualator" -- individual activities are not destroyed due to memory conditions. See http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/10/03/activities-not-destroyed-to-free-heap-space.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm have next problem. I solved it by removing the flag **FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK**